# Replacing values in multiple excel sheets using R

Tags: r, excel

I have a lot of .xlsx files that each have multiple sheets within them. I am attempting to loop through each sheet within each .xlsx file and replace certain numbers with characters. This is the code I have so far:

```
# list of workbooks
Wblistreplace <- AllWorkbooks$Full_Output[AllWorkbooks$Year == current_year]

for (x in Wblistreplace) {
  new_workbook <- loadWorkbook(paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"))
  
  new_workbook_sheets <- excel_sheets(paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"))
  
  for (sheet_name in new_workbook_sheets) {
    
    sheet <- read.xlsx(paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"), sheet = sheet_name)
    
    sheet[sheet == "9999"] <- "[z]"
    sheet[sheet == "9998"] <- "[d]"
    sheet[sheet == "9997"] <- "[x]"
    sheet[sheet == "9996"] <- "[u]"
    sheet[is.na(sheet)] <- "[x]"
    
    
  }
  saveWorkbook(new_workbookreplace,
              paste0(project_root, AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 11], ".xlsx"),
              overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

How do I actually write out the changes into each sheet before saving the workbook? I assume I am missing some sort of writeData or write.xlsx but I can't figure it out. I am just replacing values so I can't see how writeData would apply as I would then have to put in a startCol and startRow argument for where to write the new data to but that doesn't make sense if im just replacing values.

Any help much appreciated,

I have been unsure what the next step is.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover I disagree. There used to be performance problems where `for` loops could be significantly slower than (say) `sapply` or `lapply`, but that was remedied _years_ ago. When talking about column-wise or even row-wise operations in `data.frame` objects, I completely agree, often `for` loops may not be optimal. However, when iterating over files or similar, I think `for` loops can be simpler to develop, work-with, troubleshoot, etc. And when used properly, there should be no performance penalty. In this case, it think it's fine.

Comment: Help still needed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Up front, I'm assuming you do not care about cell formatting (static or conditional) in the workbooks. This process just works on the data itself, no formatting, and formulas are calculated ("realized") and written back as static data (no longer formulas).

## Setup

```r
writexl::write_xlsx(list(mt1=mtcars[1:3,], mt2=mtcars[4:6,]), "mt1.xlsx")
writexl::write_xlsx(list(mt3=mtcars[7:9,], mt4=mtcars[10:12,]), "mt2.xlsx")
writexl::write_xlsx(list(mt5=mtcars[13:15,], mt6=mtcars[16:18,]), "mt3.xlsx")
list.files(".", pattern = "xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
# [1] "./mt1.xlsx" "./mt2.xlsx" "./mt3.xlsx"
```

For demonstration on formulas, I then opened `mt1.xlsx`, and on the `"mt1"` worksheet, I changed cell `$K$2` to be `=J2+99`, where `J2` is `gear[1]`. This produces a value of `103`. I also changed the background color to red,

[image: workbook mt1.xlsx, worksheet mt1, cell color and formula]

## See what they look like

(Not required for your use, just to demo what we have *here*.)

(Notice how `mt1.xlsx$mt1$carb[1]` is now `103`, which *was* a formula on `$gear[1]` and is now a static value.

```r
lapply(setNames(nm = list.files(".", pattern = "xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)), function(xl) {
  lapply(setNames(nm = readxl::excel_sheets(xl)), function(sht) readxl::read_xlsx(xl, sht))
})
# $`./mt1.xlsx`
# $`./mt1.xlsx`$mt1
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4   103
# 2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
# $`./mt1.xlsx`$mt2
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
# 2  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 3  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
# $`./mt2.xlsx`
# $`./mt2.xlsx`$mt3
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 2  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 3  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
# $`./mt2.xlsx`$mt4
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# 2  17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
# 3  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
# $`./mt3.xlsx`
# $`./mt3.xlsx`$mt5
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
# 2  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
# 3  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
# $`./mt3.xlsx`$mt6
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
# 2  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
# 3  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
```

## Do the work

We'll change all instances of `6` with `[z]`, and `1` with `[y]`. I'm doing it for all columns at once, which makes replacement simple; there can be more-specific replacements as well, just do them to `dat` in the inner portion.

(FYI: `readxl` returns a `tibble`, and the "simple" replacement does not work on tibbles, so I convert to a base `data.frame` to do that.)

```r
for (xl in xlfiles) {
  newdat <- lapply(setNames(nm = readxl::excel_sheets(xl)), function(sht) {
    dat <- readxl::read_xlsx(xl, sheet = sht) |> as.data.frame()
    dat[dat == 6] <- "[z]"
    dat[dat == 1] <- "[y]"
    dat
  })
  writexl::write_xlsx(newdat, xl)
}
```

Notes:

- I'm using an outer `for` loop to show that it can be done with a `for` loop here, I could easily have used `lapply(setNames(nm=list.files(..)), function(xl) { ... })` as I did in the previous section. They will both work equally well. Since I don't need to try to capture the "return value" of each step of the outer loop, then `for` works fine (if we did, it's still possible, it just takes a little extra work).
- The inner loop is being done by `lapply`. The `write_xlsx` can only write to a file in one step, it cannot "add" worksheets to an existing workbook. The way to write multiple sheets to a single workbook is to pass a named list (for example, see the "Setup" section above) where the names are the worksheet tab names and the list contents are each worksheet's cell values. Because of this, we need to create a named list of worksheets for each file and then rewrite (completely overwrite) the previous file. Because of *this*, I choose to use `lapply`, which iterates over each sheet (of the `xl` file), reads it in, makes the change, and returns it as an element in the list. After `lapply`, the `newdat` is a named list, similar to the `list(mt1=..., mt2=...)` used in "Setup" above.
- By default, `write_xlsx` formats the column names as centered/bold, use `format_headers=FALSE` to change this; I'm assuming you want/need the column names to remain. The only other argument you can change is `use_zip64=`, but if it works without setting it, I suggest not setting it unless you have files larger than 4GB each.

## See what the look like *now*

```r
lapply(setNames(nm = xlfiles), function(xl) {
  lapply(setNames(nm = readxl::excel_sheets(xl)), function(sht) readxl::read_xlsx(xl, sht))
})
# $`./mt1.xlsx`
# $`./mt1.xlsx`$mt1
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec vs    am     gear carb 
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  21   [z]     160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5 0     [y]       4 103  
# 2  21   [z]     160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0 0     [y]       4 4    
# 3  22.8 4       108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6 [y]   [y]       4 [y]  
# $`./mt1.xlsx`$mt2
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear carb 
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  21.4 [z]     258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4 [y]       0     3 [y]  
# 2  18.7 8       360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0 0         0     3 2    
# 3  18.1 [z]     225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2 [y]       0     3 [y]  
# $`./mt2.xlsx`
# $`./mt2.xlsx`$mt3
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8 0         0     3     4
# 2  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20   [y]       0     4     2
# 3  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9 [y]       0     4     2
# $`./mt2.xlsx`$mt4
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  19.2 [z]    168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3 [y]       0     4     4
# 2  17.8 [z]    168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9 [y]       0     4     4
# 3  16.4 8      276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4 0         0     3     3
# $`./mt3.xlsx`
# $`./mt3.xlsx`$mt5
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
# 2  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
# 3  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
# $`./mt3.xlsx`$mt6
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec vs    am     gear carb 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8 0     0         3 4    
# 2  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4 0     0         3 4    
# 3  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5 [y]   [y]       4 [y]
```

And the top-right corner of `mt1.xlsx$mt1`? Notice it no longer has a red background and its formula is set to the static calculated value, no longer `=J2+99`. (Though it does highlight that `write_xlsx` is using a leading single-quote `'` to differentiate this as a string and not a number, since the column itself was converted to character by changing the last value to `[y]`. YMMV)

[image: workbook mt1.xlsx, worksheet mt1, changed cell]

Comment: Hi @r2evans I think I understand what you are doing but am struggling to apply your code to what I currently have.

Comment: I think your `Wblistreplace` is a vector that can be made to be filenames. Perhaps if you set `xlfiles <- paste0(project_root, Wblistreplace, ".xlsx")` and then try my loop it will work?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. That has worked and replaced everything the way I wanted it - unfortunately, It has wiped the formatting that was in the cells which I see you mentioned would happen above. Is there no way to replace values and still be able to keep all current formatting?

Comment: I know that `writexl` cannot do that, I don't know that `openxlsx` (or `openxlsx2`) can overwrite data without losing formatting. (I suggest you edit your question and add that as a prerequisite.)